# Populating XML Document with Predefined Variables

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to create an XML file that contains information which I have pulled from another file.

At the moment I have the data pulled from the file and stored in several variables. Originally I was hardcoding in the XML data using the below. I am now trying to put a variable into the TextNode rather then it being hard coded.

I understand that one type is of type Element and the other of type String but I am struggling on converting them.

Is this at all possible?

```
Element phoneNumber = document.createElement("PhoneNumber");
phoneNumber.appendChild(document.createTextNode("12345678"));
request.appendChild(phoneNumber);
```

Error - 'The method createTextNode(String) in the type Document is not applicable for the arguments (Element)'

```
Element phoneNumber = document.createElement("PhoneNumber");
phoneNumber.appendChild(document.createTextNode(phoneNumber));  <-- on here
request.appendChild(phoneNumber);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you're using now? You can just replace hardcoded values with variable names. For example, `document.createTextNode(phoneData)` instead of `document.createTextNode("12345678")`.

Comment: @TedHopp i have tried that but it is saying that the types are diiferent, one is type Element and the other String

Comment: Do you mean you are receiving that error in the code you posted? If so, on what line? If not, please post the code that generates the error. Also, what is the data type of `request`?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the error and where the error is coming up and the type of request is type Element

Comment: Well, yes, `phoneNumber` is the `Element` you just created. You need to substitute the variable that has the phone number data itself.

Comment: further up in my code i have set the value of phoneNumber = 1234, but that still isnt working

Comment: Then change one of the variable names. One declaration is hiding the other.

Comment: Ah thank you that was a silly mistake on my part, i thought it was more complicated then it was and over looked the basics, thanks again